# Java Index Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` at the line that calls for my custom fonction: 
`motCars = remplaceTirets(motAlea, motCars, lettreDon);`. 
This function is supposed to turn one or more of the dashes into the letter if the given letter equals the letter in the word) and a line in the actual function where it says:
 `tempo += tirets.charAt(j);`

The result is: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ (the amount of these dashes depends on the word chosen by the program, which works and then it asks to give a letter but when I give a letter I get:

> Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.String IndexOutOfBoundsException. String Index out of range: 1.

It's partly in french because I live in Quebec. But I'm hoping that it doesn't matter because the french words just concern the strings and words, not the logic of java. I'm a beginner and overwhelmed with all the advice on all the forums on Java. Any specific advice will be welcome.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to have a look !

Anita

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class Tp {

public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

Scanner clavier = new Scanner(System.in);
String motAlea = "";                                
String motCars = "";                
char lettreDon = Character.UNASSIGNED;              
String tempo = "";                                  
String invite = "";
String tirets = "";
int l = 0;                                  
int m = 0;                              

final String ANNONCE  = "J'ai choisi un mot a deviner\n";
final String INSTRUCT = "Entrez une lettre a la fois. L'indice d'essais: 15.\n";
final String INVITE   = "\tEntrez une lettre: ";
final String BRAVO    = "BRAVO ! Le mot a deviner etait: ";
final String DESOLE   = "DESOLE...Vous avez perdu..."; 

String[] vingtMots = {  "WATTHEUREMETRE", "HELIOGRAPH", "GRENOUILLERE",     "CONTRAROTATIF", 
                        "CUISSARDE", "BRIGANTINE", "AVITAILLEUR", "ENTREDOUBLURE", 
                        "GALLETAGE", "OEUILLERE", "CREMAILLERE", "HALTEROPHILIE", 
                        "MARTINGALE", "EMPENNAGE", "ENCOCHAGE", "DECLENCHEUR", 
                        "BIMETALLIQUE", "PIVOTEMENT", "DECLINAISON", "CROISILLON"
                        }; // tableau string        

int indexAlea = 0; 
indexAlea = (int)(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

motAlea = vingtMots[indexAlea]; 

for (l = 0; l < motAlea.length(); l++) { 
    tempo += "_";
    motCars = tempo;
} // for

System.out.print(ANNONCE);
System.out.print(INSTRUCT);
l = 0;

do {
    if (motCars.equals(motAlea)) {
    System.out.print(BRAVO + motAlea + ", " + "devine en " + m + 
    " tentatives");
    System.exit(0);
    } // if

    if (l == 15) {
        System.out.print("\n" + DESOLE + "Le mot a devine etait: " + 
        motAlea + ". " + "Au revoir... "); 
        System.exit(0); 
    } // if

    for (int i = 0; i < motAlea.length(); i++) { 
    System.out.print(motCars.charAt(i) + " ");   
    } // for

    m = l + 1;
    invite = "\t" + INVITE + m + ">  :";

    lettreDon = lecture(invite); 

    motCars = remplaceTirets(motAlea, motCars, lettreDon);

    l++;    

 } // do
    while (l < 16); {
    System.out.print("\n" + DESOLE + "Le mot a devine etait: " + motAlea + ". " 
    + "Au revoir... "); 
    } // while


} //main(...)

public static char lecture(String invite1){

Scanner clavier = new Scanner(System.in);
final String ERREUR = "La valeur entree est erronnee !\nReprenez-vous...";
final String VIDE = " ";
String retour = "";

    do { 
        try {
        System.out.print(invite1);
        retour = clavier.nextLine().trim(); // Mise en forme;

            for (int k = 0; k < retour.length(); k++) {

                if(Character.isLetter(retour.charAt(k))) {
                return retour.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
                } // if
            } // for
        } // try
        catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(ERREUR);
        }               
    }// do
    while (!retour.equals(VIDE)); {
    retour = "X";
    return retour.charAt(0);
    } // while              
} // lecture(...)

public static String remplaceTirets(String motAlea1, String tirets, 
char lettre) {
String retour;  
String tempo = ""; 

    for (int j = 0; j < motAlea1.length(); j++) { 

        String lettre1 = Character.toString(lettre);
        if (motAlea1.charAt(j) != lettre1.charAt(0)) {
        tempo += tirets.charAt(j);
        } // if     
            else {
            tempo += lettre1.charAt(0); 
            } // else   
    tirets = tempo; 
    } // for    
    return retour = tirets;         
} //remplaceTirets(...)

}//Tp
```

Comment: Please provide **the exact error/exception** with full trace back.

Comment: @Anita You will tend to get better (and faster) help if you reduce the amount of code posted. If you can remove code that you know is not part of the problem, you should, since it will help others find your problem faster.

Comment: If you're getting IndexOutOfBoundsException on charAt it's because the character index value is out of bounds for the string being indexed.  This would happen if tirets is shorter than motAlea1.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
tirets = tempo;
```

should be out of the for loop.

change your code to

```
for (int j = 0; j < motAlea1.length(); j++) { 
    String lettre1 = Character.toString(lettre);
    if (motAlea1.charAt(j) != lettre1.charAt(0)) {
        tempo += tirets.charAt(j);
    } // if     
        else {
        tempo += lettre1.charAt(0); 
    } // else   
    //tirets = tempo; //REMOVE THIS LINE
} // for 
tirets = tempo; //ADD THIS LINE
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers... su-: that works..so this problem can be considered as answered...when I get good at this I will definitely take the time to answer these kinds of newby questions in return.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a position in `tirets` based on the length of `motAlea1`. I expect that `motAlea1.length() > tirets.length()`.

```
for (int j = 0; j < motAlea1.length(); j++) { 

    String lettre1 = Character.toString(lettre);

    if (motAlea1.charAt(j) != lettre1.charAt(0)) {
        tempo += tirets.charAt(j); //THIS COULD FAIL!!!
    }else{
        tempo += lettre1.charAt(0); 
    }
    tirets = tempo; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers...I will continue searching for a proper line for tempo += tirets.charAt(0). the complete error is the following:

Answer (score 0):

In this loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < motAlea1.length(); j++) { 

    String lettre1 = Character.toString(lettre);
    if (motAlea1.charAt(j) != lettre1.charAt(0)) {
    tempo += tirets.charAt(j);
    } // if     
        else {
        tempo += lettre1.charAt(0); 
        } // else   
tirets = tempo; 
} // for
```

String `tirets` is shorter than `motAlea1` and so you're trying to retrieve a character **beyond its end**.

Comment: The complete exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException String out of range:1